# Tracking user activity in a microservice application

Tags: spring-boot, logging, microservices, event-sourcing, audit-logging

I want to keep track (with persistency) of users interactions with a microservice application developed with spring boot, so that i could consult them if something happened even maybe a year later.. One solution i found was use event sourcing and the problem was gone.. but due to some constraints i cannot go with that solution (in this project) so i was wondering..

**Question**

**How can I track all user interactions and persist them in a spring boot microservice application?**

Answer (score 0):

if all the interactions that you want to track are sent to the server, then you can persist them in the database when the request is received in the server. To know who is the user you must need a way to identify him, for example, by using a token if the user is authenticated.

However, although this can be a solution the usual way to do this is using google analytics https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/#/provision

or snowplow https://snowplowanalytics.com/

Any of them track the actions done by the user in the frontend of the application

Comment: the first approach is more feasable, if i use some kind of filter or interceptor class i could see that working, but I was wondering if there exist a spring library that does this though ?.. using the other approach is off the menu, cuz of 1-pricing and 2-not providing ip addresses (google analytics as far as i know).. and i need to track ip addresses.